# Workaround for VS 2013 SFINAE deficiencies

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, sfinae, result-of

I'm trying to fix up a library ([entityx](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx)) that does not currently compile on Windows using VS 2013.  It compiles fine on Linux with gcc and also on Windows with MinGW.

It seems the problem is with SFINAE - I guess VS 2013 doesn't properly ignore substitution failures for templates.

There is a report of this issue on Microsoft Connect, [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794707/sfinae-fai).

Before I dive into [entityx](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx), there is a sample of the problem (taken from the report at Microsoft Connect):

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

typedef int async_io_op;

struct Foo
{
    //! Invoke the specified callable when the supplied operation completes
    template<class R> inline std::pair < std::vector < future < R >> , std::vector < async_io_op >> call(const std::vector<async_io_op> &ops, const std::vector < std::function < R() >> &callables);
    //! Invoke the specified callable when the supplied operation completes
    template<class R> std::pair < std::vector < future < R >> , std::vector < async_io_op >> call(const std::vector < std::function < R() >> &callables) { return call(std::vector<async_io_op>(), callables); }
    //! Invoke the specified callable when the supplied operation completes
    template<class R> inline std::pair<future<R>, async_io_op> call(const async_io_op &req, std::function<R()> callback);
    //! Invoke the specified callable when the supplied operation completes
    template<class C, class... Args> inline std::pair<future<typename std::result_of<C(Args...)>::type>, async_io_op> call(const async_io_op &req, C callback, Args... args);
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo foo;
    std::vector<async_io_op> ops;
    std::vector < std::function < int() >> callables;
    foo.call(ops, std::move(callables));
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when attempting to compile this:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 58

Apparently, we can use `std::enable_if` to work around this problem.  However, I can't figure out how.

Does anyone know how I can fix this compile error?

**Edit**:  Full output from VS 2013:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: VS2013_SFINAE_Failure, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test_case.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(58): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(118) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Result_of<_Fty,>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fty=std::vector<std::function<int (void)>,std::allocator<std::function<int (void)>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\jarrett\downloads\vs2013_sfinae_failure\vs2013_sfinae_failure\test_case.cpp(25) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::result_of<std::vector<std::function<int (void)>,std::allocator<_Ty>> (void)>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::function<int (void)>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I remember when I worked with stuff like this.
I hope you have many stress balls, and tissues.

Comment: Can you post the entire error? The subsequent lines usually provide additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2013 compiles the code if you replace `std::result_of` with its `decltype` + `std::declval` equivalent. So change the last `Foo::call()` definition to

```
template<class C, class... Args>
inline pair<future<decltype(declval<C>()(declval<Args>()...))>, async_io_op> 
call(const async_io_op& req, C callback, Args... args);
```

If I understand the error correctly, it's related to the defect described [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html), but then it's surprising that both GCC and clang manage to compile the `result_of` code without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Praetorian.  I tried copying and pasting, but I get a `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` error now instead.

Comment: @Jarrett Well, you get that with gcc and clang also, because the `Foo::call` you're trying to call from within main hasn't been defined :)

Comment: Oh haha.  Ok well then I guess that solves it :)  Thanks @Praetorian.